# Angular: Observable subscribing in service - using it with ngOnChanges runs (too) many times

Tags: angular, subscriber, rxjs6

so I have a scenario like this (simplyfied)

- main component
- list component
- list service

where:

**main component**

```
<my-list [month]="month"></my-list>
```

**list component html**

```
<li *ngFor="let item in list | async></li>
```

**list component ts**

```
list: Observable<ListItem[]>;
@Input() month: string;
...
ngOnInit() {
  this.list = this._listService.list;
}
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  if (changes.month && !!this.month) {
     this._listService.getAllByMonth(this.month);
  }
}
```

**and finally list service**

```
private _list: BehaviorSubject<ListItem[]>;
list: Observable<ListItem[]>;

private dataStore: {
  list: ListItem[]
};

constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {
  this.dataStore = { list: [] };
  this._list= <BehaviorSubject<ListItem[]>>new BehaviorSubject([]);
  this.list= this._list.asObservable();
}

public getAllByMonth(month: string) {
   this._http.get<ListItem[]>(environment.apiPath + 'list/' + month)
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        this.dataStore.list = data;
        this._list.next(Object.assign({}, this.dataStore).list);
      },
      error => console.log('Could not load the list.')
    );
}
```

For some reason getAllByMonth get's called many, many times... even though I change the month value only 1.

How should arrange things that getAllByMonth get's called ONCE when month value changes?

Comment: Are you able to create it on stackblitz.com? and share link here

Comment: no, not really... it wouldn't work.... I simplified the code.... it should be enough to understand the problematic.... I am sure it's a silly thing... but cannot find the solution

Comment: It's clear why it's repeating. You keep mutating the `list` collection when `getAllByMonth` is called, which in turn recreates all the elements for `*ngFor` which in turn triggers `getAllByMonth` again.

Comment: @cgTag so how do you suggest I solve this?

Comment: @DS_web_developer I don't know if `trackBy` will fix your problem, but as a best practice you should always use one. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*ngFor` uses the equals `===` comparison to see if an `Array` instance has changed. When the new array and old array are not the same reference, then all the elements in the collection are recreated.

To tell `*ngFor` that it should not recreate an element, but re-use an element in the array. You have to use the `trackBy` callback function.

```
<li *ngFor="let item in list | async; trackBy: trackItem"></li>
```

Then in your component

```
public trackItem(indx: number, item: LinkItem): number {
     return item.id;
}
```

This function needs to return a value (number, string, object, etc) that yields `true` for equal `===` comparisons. This is how `ngFor` knows that it should re-use a component with that array item.

In my above example I assumed their is a unique number `id` that can be used from each `LinkItem`.

All of this stops the recursive calls to `ngOnChanges` because those components were being recreated every time `list` was updated with a new array instance.

Comment: @DS_web_developer add `console.log('constructor')` to the constructor of the component with `ngOnChanges` and see how many times it's being created.

Comment: Obviously I've done it.... and it says 8 times.... am trying to recreate in stackblitz.com ...if could get *ngFor to work there :/

Comment: well, just realised I am a morron.... instantiating the list component 8x in tabs :/ so yeah... wasted my 5h and your time.... so sorry

Comment: @DS_web_developer it happens all the time to programmers.